# How do reset SRK of TPM 2.0?

Tags: tpm

I want to reset SRK.
It can also be seen as a Factory Reset of the TPM.

I tried tpm2_clear but it doesn't work.

---

## Machine: VMWare Workstation

```
# tpm2_getcap properties-variable
TPM2_PT_PERSISTENT:
  ownerAuthSet:              0
  endorsementAuthSet:        0
  lockoutAuthSet:            1
  reserved1:                 0
  disableClear:              0
  inLockout:                 0
  tpmGeneratedEPS:           1
  reserved2:                 0
TPM2_PT_STARTUP_CLEAR:
  phEnable:                  0
  shEnable:                  1
  ehEnable:                  1
  phEnableNV:                1
  reserved1:                 0
  orderly:                   0

# tpm2_clear -c p
WARNING:esys:src/tss2-esys/api/Esys_Clear.c:282:Esys_Clear_Finish() Received TPM Error
ERROR:esys:src/tss2-esys/api/Esys_Clear.c:97:Esys_Clear() Esys Finish ErrorCode (0x00000185)
ERROR: Esys_Clear(0x185) - tpm:handle(1):hierarchy is not enabled or is not correct for the use
ERROR: Unable to run tpm2_clear
```

In VMWare, phEnable is not set even after Cold-Start.

---

## Machine: HP EliteBook 850 G5

```
~# tpm2_getcap properties-variable
TPM2_PT_PERSISTENT:
  ownerAuthSet:              0
  endorsementAuthSet:        0
  lockoutAuthSet:            1
  reserved1:                 0
  disableClear:              0
  inLockout:                 0
  tpmGeneratedEPS:           0
  reserved2:                 0
TPM2_PT_STARTUP_CLEAR:
  phEnable:                  1
  shEnable:                  0
  ehEnable:                  1
  phEnableNV:                1
  reserved1:                 0
  orderly:                   1

# tpm2_clear -c p
WARNING:esys:src/tss2-esys/api/Esys_Clear.c:282:Esys_Clear_Finish() Received TPM Error
ERROR:esys:src/tss2-esys/api/Esys_Clear.c:97:Esys_Clear() Esys Finish ErrorCode (0x000009a2)
ERROR: Esys_Clear(0x9A2) - tpm:session(1):authorization failure without DA implications
ERROR: Unable to run tpm2_clear

# tpm2_clear -c o
ERROR: Unexpected handle - TPM2_RH_OWNER
ERROR: Unknown or unsupported handle, got: "o"
ERROR: Cannot make sense of object context "o"
ERROR: Invalid lockout authorization
ERROR: Unable to run tpm2_clear
```

Is there any way SRK reset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, `tpm2_clear` clears the owner hierarchy, that is the SRK and all its child keys.

According to the [command specification (sec. 24.6)](https://trustedcomputinggroup.org/wp-content/uploads/TCG_TPM2_r1p59_Part3_Commands_pub.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A489%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C69%2C734%2C0%5D) there are multiple reasons why `tpm2_clear` could fail.

#### 1. The platform hierarchy is disabled

This error is quite subtle because it is not mentioned explicitly in the command description for `TPM2_Clear`. By default, `TPM2_Clear` operates on the platform hierarchy. However, the platform hierarchy can be disabled (`phEnable` bit clear) via the command `TPM2_HierarchyControl`:

```
tpm2_hierarchycontrol -C p phEnable clear
```

Any future use of the platform hierarchy should result in the return code `TPM2_RC_HANDLE = 0x0000010B`. However, there is no TPM command to re-enable the platform hierarchy. [Architecture specification (Sec 13.3)](https://trustedcomputinggroup.org/wp-content/uploads/TCG_TPM2_r1p59_Part1_Architecture_pub.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A333%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C69%2C427%2C0%5D):

> When phEnable is CLEAR, a _TPM_Init is required to SET it.

It seems you need to reset your TPM (toggling the hardware reset signal or power off) to re-enable the platform hierarchy.

If this does not solve your problem, see the next potential issue.

#### 2. `TPM2_Clear` Command is disabled

This is probably not your problem, because it would yield another error (return code `TPM_RC_DISABLED = 0x0000120`).

The `TPM2_Clear` command can be disabled (`disableClear` bit set). This is done via the command `TPM2_ClearControl`.  To enable clearing, call `tpm2_clearcontrol -Cp c`. Like `tpm2_clear`, `tpm2_clearcontrol` requires platform authorization.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In VMWare, phEnable is not set even after Cold-Start. So I tried in real-machine, but caused the error: "authorization failure without DA implications". Can you help me a little more?

Comment: I assume, the platform hierarchy is disabled "in firmware", i.e. before control is passed to the Linux kernel. Once it is disabled, there is nothing you can do (besides resetting the TPM which typically cannot be done via software). I'd say you need to fiddle with your hypervisor. Unfortunately I'm not very familiar with TPM virtualization.

Comment: If your productive system is not virtualized you might want to use a TPM simulator for development. The TSS (and therefore the tpm2-tools) currently supports [MsSim](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ibmswtpm2/) and [swtpm](https://github.com/stefanberger/swtpm).